# issue with seting several foreign keys in a table which will reference only one table

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

I'm creating a database that has to manage the orders of a food delivery company (for a school project). I created a menu table which naturally has to contain several dishes (starter, main course and a desert) and I also have a dish table. so the menu has to contain three `foreign keys` which reference the primary key of the dish table. But I get an error due to foreign key constraints every time I try to execute my script
here's the code for the tables (sorry, but there's an issue with inserting the code into the case)

```
create table plat(
    id_plat integer primary key,
    gluten boolean,
    végétarien boolean,
    nom varchar(30),
    catégorie varchar(30)  
);

create table menu(
    id_menu integer primary,
    entrée integer,
    plat integer,
    dessert integer,
    foreign key(entrée) references plat(id_menu),
    foreign key(plat) references plat(id_menu),
    foreign key(dessert) references plat(id_menu)
);
```

after I execute my code using `show ENGINE INNODB STATUS` I get this error:

> 2016-12-29 21:42:58 7f2116e5c700 Error in foreign key constraint of table PROJET/menu:
>   there is no index in referenced table which would contain
>   the columns as the first columns, or the data types in the
>   referenced table do not match the ones in table.
>
> Constraint:
>     CONSTRAINT "menu_ibfk_1" FOREIGN KEY ("entrée") REFERENCES "plat" ("id_menu")
>
> The index in the foreign key in table is "entrée"
>   See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html
>   for correct foreign key definition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your foreign keys definitions are not correct, you try to link `entree` field from `menu` table with `id_menu` field from `plat` table. Try this way:

```
foreign key(entrée) references plat(id_plat)
```

[Official docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html)

Comment: is it okay if my foreign keys have the same name as the primary key it references ?

Comment: @AkramBendoukha do you mean the name of the Fk itself or the field that references the primary key? (If the former, I generally try to avoid naming such keys explicitly; but it might be ok. If the latter, it is often the case that the referencing field uses the same name as the pk field referenced; whether that is good practice depends on the situation and is opinion-based even then. For example, in your case, `menu` couldn't have 3 references to `plat` without separate fields each with their own name.)